# Finding specific div element just below span with title text in cucumber

Tags: css, xpath, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber and capybara to test a web page with the following outline.

```
<span> Title 1 </span>
<span> Some text </span>
<div> link Y </div>
<span> Title 2 </span>
<span> Some text </span>
<div> link Y </div>
<span> Title 3 </span>
<span> Some text </span>
<div> link Y </div>
```

I want to click on the link below Title 2. But since all links have the same name and same css except for being asynchronous ajax calls, can I use that in a finder somehow?
I also want to design a helper method that takes the Title and finds the link for it so an exact xpath would not work.

What I have tried so far:

```
within(find("span", :text => title)) do
  within(find(:xpath, "../div")) do
    click_link 'publish'
  end
end
```

As you can tell xpaths are not my strong point.

I've also tried going through native getting the path of the capybara:node:element using: `find("span", :text => title).path` hoping to extract the child nbr of the title span using that to get the div as such `find(:xpath, "/div[N]"`). But `.path` gives me an error telling me that its not supported by my webdriver, I am using selenium webdriver since the page contains asynchronous ajax calls.

I've also tried looking at the `.native` selenium webdriver element but not found any help in there.

Please help! Also before you tell me to, no I can not change the webpage in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do:

```
title = "Title 2"
within( find(:xpath, "//span[normalize-space(text())='#{title}']/following-sibling::div[1]") ) do
    click_link 'publish'
end
```

An explanation of the xpath:

1. `//span[normalize-space(text())='#{title}']` looks for the span with the title. Note that `normalize-space(text())` is used to make handling of spaces easier by removing extra spaces. This allows specifying the `title` as "Title 2" instead of having to do " Title 2 " (ie having to specify the leading/trailing space).
2. `/following-sibling::div[1]` says that from the span found, find the first div element that follows.

Comment: Thank you very much! The explanation will ensure that I can rewrite it for future occasions as well. Great answer.